# Extract main class name from AndroidManifest

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm implementing in Java and XML parser for extracting the main class name from an AndroidManifest.xml 
What i'm doing is getting all the activity elements using Document:

```
   doc.getElementsByTagName("activity")
```

and later trying to get all the  children elements to verify if they have children  and  with values, respectively: `"android.intent.action.MAIN"` and `"android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"`. 
But if i try to get children from `<intent-filter>` elements it says that there are no children,
and watching the AndroidManifest.xml  i say is wrong. 
How can i solve this?

Comment: Try to explain what is your master plan here, maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: my plan is published here: https://github.com/idell/jManifestParser/blob/master/ManifestParser.java

Comment: Hi, i've modified the code, but now i get "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredTextImpl cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Element" Execption.
see the file on  [github](https://github.com/idell/jManifestParser/blob/master/ManifestParser.java) . Thank's all!

Comment: Hi, have you got any ideas to help me?